# PySpark: Using Split and withColumn to split a DF column with different character marks into another column

Tags: split, pyspark

Hello I have this column in a dataFrame:

|event_time|

2019-12-01 00:17:...

2019-12-01 00:17:...

2019-12-01 00:17:...

2019-12-01 00:17:...

2019-12-01 00:17:...

____________________________________________________________'

I want to split the event_time column where the day gets put into a day column and the hour gets put into an hour column.
Here is what I have so far (to note my dataFrame is called purchaseDF.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

cols = F.split(purchaseDF['event_time'],'-')

dateDF = purchaseDF.withColumn('Day',cols.getItem(2))
        
dateDF.show(10)
```

The output includes the hour as well and I am  not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.
Again, I would just like the '01' of the date to get moved to a new column.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is because the value in `cols.getItem(2)` will be everything after the second `-`, which is `01 00:17:...`.

You can use `substring` to just get the day and ignore others:

```
purchaseDF.withColumn('Day',cols.getItem(2).substr(1,2))
```

Or convert the `event_time` column to `timestamp` and use `dayofmonth` and `hour` functions:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

purchaseDF.withColumn('event_time', col('event_time').cast("timestamp"))\
            .withColumn('Day', dayofmonth('event_time'))
            .withColumn('Hour', hour('event_time')).show()
```